# Adding jQuery src to page causes an overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html

I am developing an html5 kiosk application with django that needs to fit on a 1920x1080 screen exactly without scroll bars.  The page and css are fine and fit perfectly, but just adding the jQuery script link and no other code causes the page to start showing scrollbars.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

without this, the page is fine

```
<script src="{% static 'buildingmaps/js/jquery.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but with it I get scroll bars on top and bottom.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? i remember seeing a bug report about this in an older version of jQuery.

Comment: I looked and it was 1.5.2. Been using it forever and ever in my web app template.  Updated to 1.10.1 and it is fixed, Thanks!!!